# Decrypting SharePoint shared URL using C#

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, url

Is it possible to decrypt the SharePoint shared URL like this one using c#:
https://xxx.sharepoint.com/:v:/s/xxxxx/Exxxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxx123456sdf?e=Abcdex

I have to get the original URL and append additional parameters for tracking.
I tried to append the needed parameters to the shared URL but it is being scraped out when loaded in the browser.

I have read from one of the blog post that this part is needed for authentication, and unable to get the original form of the URL:
/Exxxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxx123456sdf?e=Abcdex

I wonder if anyone here had the same requirements? Any thoughts? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

You can get file details and list item details from sharing link using CSOM and using **[GetSharingLinkData](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-csom/mt807023(v=office.15))**

Following is the code to retrieve it:

```
        ClientContext clientContext = null;
        try
        {
                            
            clientContext = new ClientContext("https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/template");
            clientContext.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials("", new NetworkCredential("", "").SecurePassword);
            Web web = clientContext.Web;
            clientContext.Load(web);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();                
            var sharingLinkData = web.GetSharingLinkData("https://contoso.sharepoint.com/:x:/s/Template/EQGqrCfJ8i9KtShkHUDD5A0B29tlZf7sd6pfQtdlYbX_kQ?e=FRUsmM");
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();


            if (sharingLinkData.Value.ObjectType == Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Sharing.SharedObjectType.File)
            {
                File file = web.GetFileById(sharingLinkData.Value.ObjectUniqueId);
                clientContext.Load(file);                    
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                Console.WriteLine(file.ServerRelativeUrl);
            }               
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            if (clientContext != null)
            {
                clientContext.Dispose();
            }             
        }
```

In above code, I have hardcoded URL for Site while building ClientContext object with assumption that at least I know that from which site sharing link belongs to. If you even don't know that sharing link can be from any of the site from SharePoint then you will need at least some string operation to get site URL like replacing **:x:/s** with "**sites**" and remove other part after site name.

Comment: thank you for your answer, @Kalpesh Vaghela . what if the scenario is sharepoint shared links are from different owners, is there a way to decrypt it without the need for sharepoint online credentials? 

also, when i tried to replace :x:/s with "sites" and removed the details after the site name, it is expected that the sharepoint has prompted with to request for access, right?

Comment: Without online credentials it's not possible

Comment: Because in order to connect with SharePoint (CSOM), authentication is compulsory